# Force reloading ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

Recently I [learned](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html) that adding css styles to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` can do some tricks to the visual appearance of gtk-3.0 based applications. Yet restarting the application after each change while trying to find the best settings is quite cumbersome.

When switching themes, the application immediately changes to the new theme, but it seems to ignore changes to `gtk.css`. Is there a way to have it reload that file too?

Comment: Are you programming in C?

Comment: 1999, roughly was the last time I programmed in C :-) Why are you asking?

Comment: If I change the color in `* { caret-color: #000000; }` in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`, all I need to do is to save the file. **After** that, if I open a *compliant* application such as mousepad, the text editor in Xubuntu, the edit is effective. This is **without** changing the gtk3 theme. (By *compliant*, I mean applications that don't set their own caret color.)

Comment: @DKBose OP was specifically asking about *not* having to restart the application.

Comment: "Why are you asking?" He is implying that the program reads the theme data once at program startup.

Answer (score 2):

When I tweak `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and reload the theme I instantly see the result, so at least the GTK applications that matter to me instantly pick up the changes. (I'm not sure what a GTK app needs to do to subscribe to theme changes, but that may be behind WinEunuuchs2Unix's question.)

To make my life easier when tweaking gtk.css, I'm using Ikbel's bash function `reload_gtk_theme` (see https://askubuntu.com/a/1110354/304643). It basically saves, clears and restores your GTK theme using gsettings.